# Push Data to JSONModel

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have a model with following data:

```
oData_main = {EmployeeName: "abc", EmployeeID:"123"};
```

I want to add data from another model to my model, so that resultant model data will look like this.

```
oData_phone:{home:"789",office:"567"} `//this is a temporary variable.`

oData_main= {EmployeeName: "abc", EmployeeID:"123", phone:{home:"789",office:"567"}};
```

I'm trying to do this in SAP UI5 application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSONModel's [`setProperty`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#setProperty) method:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    EmployeeName: "abc",
    EmployeeID: "123"
});
oModel.setProperty("/phone", {
    home: "789",
    office: "567"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[setData](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#setData) method of `JSONModel` has parameter to merge new data with existing one.

Below is the code for it

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    EmployeeName: "abc",
    EmployeeID: "123"
});
var oNewData = {
    phone: {
        home: "789",
        office: "567"
    }
};
oModel.setData(oNewData, true);
```